how to run unit testing in create react app which importing tsx file
So, i made a create-react-app, and it already has npm run test
now, I am importing one library,
import { createWeb3Modal } from '@web3modal/ethers/react'
and this react is imported from here
node_modules/@web3modal/ethers/dist/types/exports/react.tsx
and my App.jsx is in jsx, and this react imported files is in tsx, so, when I run npm run test,
it gives me error of
FAIL  src/components/App/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@web3modal/ethers/react' from 'src/components/App/App.jsx'

    Require stack:
      src/components/App/App.jsx
      src/components/App/App.test.js

    > 1 | import { createWeb3Modal } from '@web3modal/ethers/react'

how to solve this, infact I tried to install typescript still same issue.
my package.json
   {
 "name": "abc",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@sentry/cli": "^2.31.0",
   "@sentry/react": "^7.108.0",
   "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.28.2",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
   "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
   "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
   "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
   "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
   "@web3modal/ethers": "^4.0.13",
   "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
   "eth-connect": "^6.2.4",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.1",
   "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
   "recoil": "^0.7.7",
   "redux": "^5.0.1",
   "typescript": "^5.4.5",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build && npm run sentry:sourcemaps",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   "postbuild": "rimraf ./build/**/*.map"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": [
     "react-app",
     "react-app/jest"
   ]
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "eslint": "^8.57.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
   "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
   "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.6.2",
   "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
   "sass": "^1.72.0"
 }
}

can anyone help me to solve this...

so, i create file babel.config.js on rootLevel
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
}


then i created jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/helper/setupTests.js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx|(?!deck.gl)|ng-dynamic)'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
    TextEncoder: require('util').TextEncoder,
    TextDecoder: require('util').TextDecoder,
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
}


and created __ mock __ directory and in that created fileMock.js
and added
module.exports = 'test-file-stub'

and did lots of npm i -D
text-encoding
jest-environment-jsdom
jest
identity-obj-proxy
@babel/preset-react
@babel/preset-env
@babel/core
ts-jest
babel-jest

and changed my test script as
"test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",

and now showing no error, and it gets my test cases passed.
